# Allowing access to multiple companies using JWT Claim

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I am new to OIDC/OAuth2 and am looking to set up IS4 a single sign on server. I have an idea for a design but am not sure if it is a correct use of claims.

We have multiple apps used by different companies. Normally, a given identity would only have access to the resources across these apps for a single company, however some might have access to those of multiple companies (for example, an accountant who did the books for multiple clients).

I was thinking to provide these company ids as claims in the JWT. Would this be appropriate or is there a more commonly accepted way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally steer clear of this and keep the authorisation side of things inside the client app or API. I.e. company 1 and company 2's databases say that user xyz can access them and they do their checks locally.